# ActiveMQ connection in Fabric8 using Blueprint instead of DS

Tags: activemq-classic, blueprint-osgi, fabric8

In **Fabric8**, the preferred way to obtain an ActiveMQ connection is via the [**mq-fabric** profile](http://fabric8.io/gitbook/brokerClients.html), which provides an ActitveMQConnection object via Declarative Services.  [An example of this is given on GitHub](https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8/tree/master/fabric/fabric-examples/fabric-activemq-demo), which works just fine.

However, I've yet to find a way for Declarative Services and Blueprint Services to collaborate in Fabric8 (or any OSGI-environment, really), thus, my OSGI application must either use DS or blueprint.  Mixing both doesn't seem to be an option.

If you want to use blueprint (which I do), you must first create a broker through the web UI, then go back to the console and type **cluster-list**, finding the port that Fabric8 assigned to the broker and then configure a connection in blueprint like so:

```
<bean id="activemqConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
  <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://mydomain:33056" />
  <property name="userName" value="admin" />
  <property name="password" value="admin" />
</bean>
```

While this does work, it's not exactly deployment-friendly, as it involves a few manual steps that I'd like to avoid if possible.  The main issue is that I don't know what that port is going to be.  I've combed through the config files and couldn't find it anywhere.

Is there a cleaner, more automated way to obtain an ActiveMQ connection in Fabric8 via blueprint, or must we use Declarative Services?

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled across a solution to this issue in the [fabric-camel-demo](https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8/blob/master/fabric/fabric-examples/fabric-camel-demo/src/main/resources/OSGI-INF/blueprint/fabric-camel-demo.xml), which illustrates how to instantiate an ActiveMQConnectionFactory bean in Fabric8 via Blueprint.

```
<!-- use the fabric protocol in the brokerURL to connect to the ActiveMQ broker registered as default name -->
<!-- notice we could have used amq as the component name in Camel, and avoid any configuration at all,
as the amq component is provided out of the box when running in fabric -->
<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="discovery:(fabric:default)"/>
    <property name="userName" value="admin"/>
    <property name="password" value="admin"/>
</bean>
```

Hope this helps!